# Visual studio меняет время, пришедшее от сервиса

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wcf

Уважаемые форумчане, подскажите, пожалуйста, с таким вопросом.
Есть удаленный Soap сервис. От этого сервиса по запросу получаем некую информацию, в состав информации входит дата и время (важный параметр).
При обращении к сервису через программку SOAPSonar мы получаем дату, к примеру, 2014-08-19 20:00 +6:00.
А при обращении через программу при дебаге в VS 2013 я наблюдаю дату 014-08-19 **18:00**,
причем я никакого приведения по времени не делаю и погрешность в часах недопустима.
При изменении часового пояса на локальном компе до часового пояса сервера, где расположен сервис, время приходит нормальное (2014-08-19 20:00).
Подскажите, что делать, чтобы избежать искажения такого времени.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто, и студия тут ни при чем. Время, которое DateTime, может храниться в одном из двух форматов - местном (я так понимаю, я вас это UTC+4) или UTC. Когда приходит время с указанием часового пояса UTC+6, лучшее, что может сделать десериализатор - это сконвертировать его в местный пояс UTC+4.

Вариантов решения вашей проблемы аж четыре.

Вариант первый. Забить. Данное преобразование, совершаемое десериализатором, совершенно корректно и обратимо.

Вариант второй. Использовать тип данных DateTimeOffset вместо DateTime - он может хранить дату-время в любом часовом поясе.

Вариант третий. Перевести как клиент, так и сервер на использование UTC времени.

Вариант четвертый. Изменить сервер так, чтобы он передавал время в Unspecified формате (т.е. без указания часового пояса). Не знаю, зачем это нужно - но преобразовываться такое время также не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Не передавать время клиента на сервер, а на сервере фиксить время в которое был запрошен конкретный метод... И сама ситуция при которой возникает такой эффект неясна... Это я применил навык телапатии...

Comment: скорее всего дата приходит верно, просто при просмотре в отладчике она отображается в локальной таймзоне. в любом случае вопрос стоит закрыть - сомневаюсь что топикастер вернется через год чтобы уточнить подробности.

Comment: ))) А вдруг, кому-то будет полезно...))) топикастер и так понятно что решил этот вопрос уже давно... Ну а вдруг)))

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, происходит перевод времени из указанного часового пояся (+6) в часовой пояс сервера, на котором запущена программа.

Варианты:

- Пересылать время с учётом часового пояса.
- Пересылать без часового пояса.
- Пересылать строку и самому её парсить.